# Using custom python installation for Passenger wsgi deployment

Tags: python, django, passenger, dreamhost

I have been developing a django project locally and and trying to deploy it to my dreamhost account. I have compiled instructions from many outdated tutorials and gotten myself a custom installation of python and a virutalenv under Python 3.4.3

Now I am to the point where I'm trying to set up my `passenger_wsgi.py` to use the virtual environment I have set up. This is what the basic application looks like(not even touching django yet):

```
import sys, os

INTERP = os.path.expanduser("~/venv/bin/python")
if sys.executable != INTERP: os.execl(INTERP, INTERP, *sys.argv)

def application(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-type', 'text/html')])
    return ["Hello, world! from %s: %s\n" % (sys.version, sys.executable)]
```

If I remove the 2nd and 3rd lines, the program works perfectly under Dreamhost's Python 2.7.3 installation. However when I include them, I get an empty response when making a request.

I have tried many different methods of checking the executable, but can't get any of them to work correctly. Why would it be an empty response? Shouldn't there be an error if it didn't work right? I am finding nothing in my error logs.

Comment: Hi did you find the solution ? I am facing a similar problem of passenger not loading the custom python installed

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I forgot about this question. I'll post an answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I wasn't inserting my python into the system path.

```
sys.path.insert(0,'$HOME/venv/bin')
```

Here is what it the full solution looks like with a django project. This should work with any wsgi compatible `application`.

```
import sys, os
cwd = os.getcwd()
sys.path.append(cwd)
sys.path.append(cwd + '/my_project')

INTERP = os.path.expanduser("~/venv/bin/python")

if sys.executable != INTERP: os.execl(INTERP, INTERP, *sys.argv)

sys.path.insert(0,'$HOME/venv/bin')
sys.path.insert(0,'$HOME/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django')
sys.path.insert(0,'$HOME/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "my_project.settings"
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```